# How to deal with a long table?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a very long horizontal table. I rotated it to a vertical one, and would like it to be in the same page of the `Appendix`. However, it was still so long that it was automatically moved to the next page, and left one blank page. Is there any idea how to deal with this table? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section*{Appendix I: Tables}
\lipsum

\begin{sidewaystable}\hspace*{1cm}
\footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.01pt}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{0.05pt}} *{18}{c}}
\toprule
\bfseries Model & \multicolumn{18}{c}{\bfseries Parameters} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-18}
& $\omega$ & $\phi$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma_1$ & $\gamma_2$ &     $\gamma_3$ & 
$\gamma_4$ & $\gamma_5$ & $\gamma_6$ & $\theta_1$  & $\theta_2$ & $\theta_3$ & $\theta_4$ 
& $\varphi_1$ & $\varphi_2$ & $\varphi_3$ \\
\misrule
\bfseries 1
& 0.235 & 0.766 & 0.0114 & 0.0028 & 0.172 & - & - & - & - & - & -
& - & -  & - & - & -  & -  \\
\bfseries 2
& - & 0.998  & 0.0032 & 0.0002 &  -0.0058 & -0.1887& - & - & - & - & 0.593 &
0.232 & - & - &  0.1476 & -0.1377 & -0.0288 \\
\bfseries 3
& - & 0.892 & 0.0662  & -0.0028 &  -0.0020 & -0.0452 &-0.2072& - & - & - &      0.0389 & 0.6374 & -  & -  & 0.661 & -0.204 & -0.073 \\
\bfseries 4
& 1 & - & - & - & 0.0003 & -0.0006 &  -0.0005 & 0.0002
-&-& &  0.823 & - & - & - & 0.0454 & -0.1384 \\
\bfseries 5
& 1 & - &  0.0054 & - & 0.0010 & -0.0002 & 0.0006 & -0.0020 & 0.0003 & -0.0007     & 0.8524 & 0.2764 & -0.2393& 0.0348 & 0.0395 & -0.4177&- \\
\midrule
\bfseries 6
& 0 & 0.42 & 0.0093& 0.0012 & 0.0052 & - & - & - & - & - & -
& - & - & - & - & - & -  \\
\bfseries 7
& 1 & 0.869  & -0.0238 & 0.0138 & -0.0055 & -0.1819 & - & - & - & - & -0.0055
& -0.1810 & - & - & -0.249 & 0.734 & - \\
\bfseries 8
& - & 0.944  & 0.0241 & 0.0010 & 0.0276 & -0.0508 & -0.2321 & - & - & - & 0.8437
& -0.0006 & - & - & -0.2746 & -0.1223 & 0.0077 & - \\
\bfseries 9
& 1 & 0.856 & -0.115 & 0.0207 & 0.0005 & -0.0010 & 0.0037 & 0.0005 & - & - & 0.893
& - & - & - & -0.1 & -0.184 & - \\
\bfseries 10
& 1 & 1 & -0.0069 & 0.0002 & -0.0002 & -0.0007 & -0.0001 & -0.0001 & -0.0001 &     -0.0010 & 0.831 & -0.131 & - & - & - & -0.131 & -0.218  \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{18}{l}{1: DSHW(7, 364) ; 2: BATS(7, 365); 3: BATS(7, 91, 365); 4:     TBATS(7, 365); 5: TBATS(7, 91, 365)} \\
\multicolumn{18}{l}{6: LR+DSHW(7, 364) ; 7: LR+BATS(7, 365); 8:LR+BATS(7, 91, 365); 9: LR+TBATS(7, 365); 10: LR+TBATS(7, 91, 365)} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Parameters chosen for all models}\label{tab:Hparameters}
\end{sidewaystable}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have problem to understanding, where/how to be table positioned. Now all looks ok. Do you like to have some other text on the page, where is the table?

Comment: @Zarko I would like my table to be in the same page of the `Appendix` title. See the picture, the table is in the second page of Appendix, which does not look nice.

Comment: Please, than change your MWE accordingly. Add `appendix` as you use and than table. As you like to have table, `sidewaystable` is right approach. It always occupy whole page.

Comment: @Zarko Sorry for not being clear. I just added `appendix` in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a sideways table, if you swap rows and columns and reduce the value of `\tabcolsep`. Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
 \usepackage{geometry}%
 \usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}%
\usepackage[inline]{  enumitem} 
 \usepackage{graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l S[table-format=1.4]*{4}{S[table-format=-1.4]} S[table-format=1.4]*{4}{S[table-format=-1.4]}@{}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\bfseries Model } \\
 & \bfseries 1 &{\bfseries 2} & {\bfseries 3} & {\bfseries 4} & {\bfseries 5} & {\bfseries 6} & {\bfseries 7} & {\bfseries 8} & {\bfseries 9} & {\bfseries 10} \\
 \midrule
 $\omega$ &0.2350 & {–} & {–} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & {–} & 1 & 1 \\
 $\phi$ & 0.766 & 0.998 &0.892 & {–} & {–} & 0.42 & 0.869 & 0.944 & 0.856 & 1 \\
 $\alpha$ & 0.0114 & 0.0032 & 0.0662 & {–} & 0.0054 & 0.0093 & -0.0238 & 0.0241 & -0.115 & -0.0069\\
 $\beta$ & 0.0028 & 0.0002 & -0.0028 & {–} & {–} & 0.0012 & 0.0138 & 0.0010 & 0.0207 & 0.0002 \\
 \addlinespace
 $\gamma_1$ & 0.172 & -0.0058 & -0.0020 & 0.0003 & 0.0010 &0.0052 & -0.0055 & 0.0276 & 0.0005 & -0.0002 \\
 $\gamma_2$ & {–} & -0.1887 & -0.0452 & -0.0006 & -0.0002 & {–} & -0.1819 & -0.0508 &-0.0010 & -0.0007\\
 $\gamma_3$ & {–} & {–} & -0.2072 & -0.0005 & 0.0006 & {–} & {–} & -0.2321 &0.0037 & -0.0001\\
$\gamma_4$ & {–} & {–} & {–} & 0.0002 & -0.0020 & {–} & {–} & {–} & 0.0005 & -0.0001 \\
\llap{\smash{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\bfseries Paramètres}}\quad} $\gamma_5$ & {–} & {–} & {–} & {–} & 0.0003 & {–} & {–} & {–} & {–} & -0.0001 \\
 $\gamma_6$ & {–} & {–} & {–} & {–} & -0.0007 & {–} & {–} & {–} & {–} & -0.0010 \\
 \addlinespace
$\theta_1$ & {–} & 0.593 & 0.0389 & 0.823 & 0.8524 & {–} & -0.0055 & 0.8437 & 0.893 & 0.831 \\
 $\theta_2$ & {–} & 0.232 & 0.6374 & {–} & 0.2764 & {–} & -0.1810 & -0.0006 & {–} & -0.131 \\
$\theta_3$ & {–} & {–} & {–} & {–} & -0.2393 & {–} & {–} & {–} & {–} & {–} \\
$\theta_4$ & {–} & {–} & {–} & {–} & 0.0348 & {–} & {–} & {–} & {–} & {–} \\
\addlinespace
$\varphi_1$ & {–} & 0.1476 & 0.661 & 0.0454& 0.0395 & {–} & -0.249 & -0.2746 & -0.1 & {–} \\%?
$\varphi_2$ & {–} & -0.1377 & -0.204 & -0.1384 & -0.4177 & {–} & 0.734 & -0.1223 & -0.184 & -0.131 \\
$\varphi_3$ & {–} & -0.0288 & -0.073 & {–} & {–} & {–} & {–} & 0.0077 & {–} & -0.218\\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{11}{p{\linewidth}}{
\begin{enumerate*}[label =\arabic*: , itemjoin =\enspace]
  \item DSHW(7, 364)\,;
  \item BATS(7, 365)\,;
  \item BATS(7, 91, 365)\,;
  \item TBATS(7, 365)\,;\newline
  \item TBATS(7, 91, 365)\,;
  \item LR+DSHW(7, 364)\,;
  \item LR+BATS(7, 365)\,;
  \item LR+BATS(7, 91, 365)\,;\newline
  \item LR+TBATS(7, 365)\,;
  \item LR+TBATS(7, 91, 365).
\end{enumerate*}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Parameters chosen for all models}\label{tab:Hparameters}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you put huge effort to rewrite table (to only sensible form) (+1), short overview show, that only first `S` column is without minus sign, so the code line `\begin{tabular}{@{}l S[table-format=1.4]*{4}{S[table-format=-1.4]} S[table-format=1.4]*{4}{S[table-format=-1.4]}@{}}` can be `\begin{tabular}{@{}l S[table-format=1.4]*{9}{S[table-format=-1.4]} @{}}` (I was to lazy to do the same)

Comment: You're right. Having to swap made me think the 6th column had no signed number. I'll fix that (columns 5 and 6 are too close). Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @Zarko: Finally the 6th column has no signed  numbers. It was me who lost an ampersand.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Swapping rows and columns is the best result.

Answer (score 2):

`sidewaystable` is a float which reserves a separate page for itself. In this case, you can rotate a `tabular` inside the normal `table` environment. To achieve this, just add `\usepackage{graphicx}` at the preamble and use `\rotatebox{90}{ ..<your tabular here>.. }`. Note that I have set `fontsize` to `\tiny` to see the effect because your table is too tall (in the final document, you may not need this and it is a better choice not to add any text in that page).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section*{Appendix I: Tables}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{table}[!tb]
\centering\sffamily
\footnotesize
\caption{Parameters chosen for all models}\label{tab:Hparameters}
\vspace{.1em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.01pt}
\rotatebox{90}{%
  \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{0.05pt}} *{18}{c}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Model} & \multicolumn{18}{c}{\textbf{Parameters ($\times10^{-3}$)}} \\
  \cmidrule(l){2-18}
  & $\omega$ & $\phi$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma_1$ & $\gamma_2$ & $\gamma_3$ & $\gamma_4$ & $\gamma_5$ & $\gamma_6$ & $\theta_1$  & $\theta_2$ & $\theta_3$ & $\theta_4$ 
  & $\varphi_1$ & $\varphi_2$ & $\varphi_3$ \\
  \midrule
  \textbf{1}  & 235  &766 & 11.4& 2.8 & 172& - & - & - & - & - & -  & - & -  & - & - & -  & -  \\
  \textbf{2}  & -    &998 & 3.2 & 0.2 &  -5.8 & -188.7& - & - & - & - & 593&  232& - & - &  147.6 & -137.7 & -28.8 \\
  \textbf{3}  & -    &892 & 66.2& -2.8 &  -2.0 & -45.2 &-207.2& - & - & - &      38.9 & 637.4 & -  & -  & 661& -204& -73\\
  \textbf{4}  & 1000 & -  & -   & - & 0.3 & -0.6 &  -0.5 & 0.2  -&-& &  823& - & - & - & 45.4 & -138.4 \\
  \textbf{5}  & 1000 & -  &  5.4& - & 1.0 & -0.2 & 0.6 & -2.0 & 0.3 & -0.7     & 852.4 & 276.4 & -239.3& 34.8 & 39.5 & -417.7&- \\
  \midrule
  \textbf{6}  & 0    & 42 & 9.3 & 1.2 & 5.2 & - & - & - & - & - & -  & - & - & - & - & - & -  \\
  \textbf{7}  & 1000 &869 &-23.8& 13.8 & -5.5 & -181.9 & - & - & - & - & -5.5  & -181 & - & - & -249& 734& - \\
  \textbf{8}  & -    &944 & 24.1& 1 & 27.6 & -50.8 & -232.1 & - & - & - & 843.7  & -0.6 & - & - & -274.6 & -122.3 & 7.7 & \\
  \textbf{9}  & 1000 &856 &-115 & 20.7 & 0.5 & -1 & 3.7 & 0.5 & - & - & 893 & - & - & - & -1 &-184& - \\
  \textbf{10} & 1000 & 1  & -6.9& 0.2 & -0.2 & -0.7 & -0.1 & -0.1 & -0.1 &     -1 & 831& -131& - & - & - & -131& -218 \\
  \bottomrule
  \addlinespace
  \multicolumn{18}{l}{1: DSHW(7, 364) ; 2: BATS(7, 365); 3: BATS(7, 91, 365); 4: TBATS(7, 365)}\\
  \multicolumn{18}{l}{5: TBATS(7, 91, 365); 6: LR+DSHW(7, 364) ; 7: LR+BATS(7, 365)} \\
  \multicolumn{18}{l}{8: LR+BATS(7, 91, 365); 9: LR+TBATS(7, 365); 10: LR+TBATS(7, 91, 365)}
  \end{tabular}
}%
\end{table}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem is that once I delete `\tiny`, the table will get too tall again to even overlap the page number in the bottom.

Comment: @Jeannie  - To reduce the size of your table, you can follow one or more of the many techniques like using `\sffamily` for the table--it is normally narrow--and change all number representations using `\times 10^3` in the headings to reduce number of trailing zeros, etc.

Comment: Okay I see. I will try it and have a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I cant reproduce table as you show on image.

Comment: @Jeannie  - See my updated answer with the suggested reductions. I repeat again, however, there nothing wrong with a table being in a single page!.

Comment: @Zarko  - Just copy-paste my code into your editor, does it raise any errors?

Comment: No errors, only result is different as it is shown in your answer ...

Comment: @Zarko   - Ummm! that's a bit confusing, it may be a different version issue, with me it shows `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.2.24)` and I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: my comment consider your answer version before your edits. now image is generating by recent code version, however, on the page is not present section title (which make me big headache in preparing my answer, so on the end I decide to preserve `sidewaystable`, but change formatting table. Use of `\sffamily` is good idea)

Comment: Thanks @AboAmmar, it works. Does `\sffamily` change the font of the contents in the table.

Comment: @Jeannie  - Yes, a sans serif type is usually narrower than its serif counterpart. You know, the serifs are those small decorative flourishes on the ends of some of the strokes that make up letters and symbols. Sans serifs, on the other hand, do not have these details or flourishes.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Your table is really huge! To put it on the same page where is title of appendix, is not possible or its content become unreadable small. The best what you can do, to my opinion, is use `\afterpage{\clearpage}` macro from `afterpage` package. With it the table will appear on page after title:

[image]

If you not like this solution, than you stick with suggestion in answer of AboAmmar. My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{showframe}  % <-- added
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{afterpage}  % <-- added
\usepackage{graphicx}   % <-- added
\usepackage{caption}    % <-- added
\usepackage{siunitx}    % <-- added

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{Tables}
\afterpage{\clearpage}
    \begin{sidewaystable}[htb]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.2pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}
                l
          *{ 2}{S[table-format=1.3]}
          *{16}{S[table-format=-1.4]}
                @{} }
    \toprule
\textbf{M} & \multicolumn{18}{c}{\bfseries Parameters} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-18}
    & {$\omega$}    & {$\phi$}      & {$\alpha$}    & {$\beta$}
    & {$\gamma_1$}  & {$\gamma_2$}  & {$\gamma_3$}  & {$\gamma_4$} 
    & {$\gamma_5$}  & {$\gamma_6$}  & {$\theta_1$}  & {$\theta_2$}
    & {$\theta_3$}  & {$\theta_4$}  & {$\varphi_1$} & {$\varphi_2$} 
    & {$\varphi_3$}   \\
\midrule
\bfseries 1
& 0.235 & 0.766 & 0.0114 & 0.0028 & 0.172 & {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} & {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} & {-}  \\
\bfseries 2
& {-} &  0.998  & 0.0032 & 0.0002 &  -0.0058 & -0.1887& {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  0.593 &
0.232 & {-} &  {-} &   0.1476 & -0.1377 & -0.0288 \\
    \addlinespace[2ex]
\bfseries 3
& {-} &  0.892 & 0.0662  & -0.0028 &  -0.0020 & -0.0452 & -0.2072 & {-} &  {-} &  {-} &       0.0389 & 0.6374 & {-} &  {-} &  0.661 & -0.204 & -0.073 \\
\bfseries 4
& 1 & {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  0.0003 & -0.0006 &  -0.0005 & 0.0002 &
{-} &  {-} &   &  0.823 & {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  0.0454 & -0.1384 \\
    \addlinespace[2ex]
\bfseries 5
& 1 & {-} &   0.0054 & {-} &  0.0010 & -0.0002 & 0.0006 & -0.0020 & 0.0003 & -0.0007     & 0.8524 & 0.2764 & -0.2393& 0.0348 & 0.0395 & -0.4177 & {-} \\
%\midrule
\bfseries 6
& 0 & 0.42 & 0.0093& 0.0012 & 0.0052 & {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} & {-}  \\
    \addlinespace[2ex]
\bfseries 7
& 1 & 0.869  & -0.0238 & 0.0138 & -0.0055 & -0.1819 & {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  -0.0055
& -0.1810 & {-} &  {-} &  -0.249 & 0.734 & {-} \\
\bfseries 8
    & {-}       &  0.944    & 0.0241    & 0.0010   & 0.0276    & -0.0508   
    & -0.2321   & {-}       &  {-}      &  {-}     &  0.8437   & -0.0006   
    & {-}       &  {-}      & -0.2746   & -0.1223   & 0.0077   &    \\
    \addlinespace[2ex]
\bfseries 9
& 1 & 0.856 & -0.115 & 0.0207 & 0.0005 & -0.0010 & 0.0037 & 0.0005 & {-} &  {-} &  0.893
& {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  -0.1 & -0.184 & {-} \\
\bfseries 10
& 1 & 1 & -0.0069 & 0.0002 & -0.0002 & -0.0007 & -0.0001 & -0.0001 & -0.0001 &     -0.0010 & 0.831 & -0.131 & {-} &  {-} &  {-} &  -0.131 & -0.218  \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{18}{p{0.8\linewidth}}{1: DSHW(7, 364) ; 2: BATS(7, 365); 3: BATS(7, 91, 365); 4:     TBATS(7, 365); 5: TBATS(7, 91, 365);
6: LR+DSHW(7, 364) ; 7: LR+BATS(7, 365); 8:LR+BATS(7, 91, 365); 9: LR+TBATS(7, 365); 10: LR+TBATS(7, 91, 365)}
\label{tab:Hparameters}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Parameters chosen for all models. (M: Model)}
\end{sidewaystable}

    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! I would like the table to closely follow the section title, not be in the next page.

Comment: Thank you so much. The table looks nicer than it used to be, but still shows in the next page. I understand that there is no possible way to make the table looks nice and gets right position at the same time. I think I will stick with AboAmmar's answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should ask yourself, what is purpose of such huge table? It is matter if it looks nice, but if someone can find it usable and can find in it information on simple way, without use of magnifying glass ...